# Prove that for all sets $A$ and $B$, $( A \cup B ) - B = A$ implies $A \cap B =\varnothing$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, alternative-proof

In the following proof we harness properties such as:
For all set $A$,

(i) $A = A - \varnothing$

(ii) $A \cap\varnothing=\varnothing$

Proof:

Let $A$ and $B$ be arbitrary sets and suppose $( A \cup B ) - B = A$.

Given (i) then $$( A \cup B ) - B = A - \varnothing.$$

So then, $( A \cup B ) = A$ and $B = \varnothing$.

That being so,
$$A \cap B = ( A \cup B ) \cap \varnothing = \varnothing$$

If we apply (ii) to the foregoing equivalence relation. Therefore
$$A \cap B = \varnothing$$

Is this proof right? if it is I would like to see alternative ones.

Comment: Your “So then” seems to assume that if $A-B=C-D$, then $A=C$ and $B=D$. That is very much not the case. For example, $A=\{1,2\}$, $B=\{2,3\}$, $C=\{1,4,5\}$, $D=\{4,5\}$ satisfy $A-B=C-D$, but $A\neq C$ and $B\neq D$.

Comment: I think that is not true. It looks as though you compare the set on the left and right. But if you expand the term  $$A=(A\cup B)-B=(A\cup B)\cap B'=(A\cap B')\cup(B\cap B')=A\cap B'$$ which means $\displaystyle A=A\cap B'$ or $\displaystyle A\cap B=\emptyset$

Comment: There is no "cancellation law" for sets like you used, as @ArturoMagidin rightly points out.

Comment: "(A∪B)−B=A−∅.

So then, (A∪B)=A
and B=∅."   WRONG!!!!!!!  $M\setminus K = N\setminus W$ in no way shape or form means that $M=N$ and $K = W$.  Consider $A=\{1,2\}$ and $B=\{3\}$ then $A\cup B=\{1,2,3\}$ and $(A\cup B)\setminus B=\{1,2\}=A\setminus \emptyset$  So we hav $(A\cup B)\setminus B = A\setminus \emptyset$ but $A\cup B\ne A$ and $B\ne \emptyset$.

Comment: See [post with identical but non-MathJax title by the same poster](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3727067/prove-that-for-all-sets-a-and-b-a-%e2%88%a9-b-%e2%88%85-implies-a-%e2%88%aa-b-b-a). I’m voting to close this as duplicate. OP: **please** use MathJax.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $x \in A \cap B$ existed. Then $x \in A$ but also $x \in A \cup B$ and $x \in B$ so that $x \notin (A \cup B) - B$. This contradicts the starting assumption that $A=(A\cup B)-B$, so $A \cap B = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

> So then, ( A ∪ B ) = A and B = ∅.

No, that is not valid.   For instance: $(\{1,2,5\}\cup \{3,4\})\smallsetminus\{3,4\}=\{1,2,5\}\smallsetminus \emptyset$ does *not* entail that $\{3,4\}=\emptyset$

---

**Hint:** Show by definition of *set difference* and *distribution* that : $(A\cup B)\smallsetminus B = (A\smallsetminus B)\cup(B\smallsetminus B)$.  Thus since the LHS equals $A$, therefore....

Answer (score 0):

By definition of $X=C-B$, no element of $X$ lies in $B$. Hence, if $A=(A\cup B)-B$, no element of $A$ lies in $B$, and of course, conversely no element of $B$ lies in $A$, which means $A\cap B=\varnothing$.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose $(A\cup B) \setminus B = A$.

Let $x \in A\cap B$.

Then $x \in A$ and $x\in B$.  Then $x \in B$ so $x\not \in M\setminus B$ for any set $M$ so $x\not \in (A\cup B) \setminus B$.  So $x \not \in A$. But that's a contradiction.

So if $(A\cup B)\setminus B =A$ then $x \in A\cap B$ is impossible.  So $A\cap B=\emptyset$.

Not this in *no* way means $B$ is empty; just $A$ and $B$ are dijoint.

.....

Alternatively.  If $(A\cup B)\setminus B = A$ then if $x \in A$ then $x\in (A\cup B) \setminus B$ so $x \not \in B$.  So $x$ in both $A$ and $B$ is impossible so $A\cap B=\emptyset.

Or....

If $(A\cup B)\setminus B = A$ and if $x \in B$ then $x\not \in (A\cup B)\setminus B = A$ so $x$ in both $B$ and $A$ is impossible.

....

An alternative way would be to prove that $(M\cup N)\setminus N = M\setminus N$ always.  I'll leave that proof to you.

That means $(A\cup B) \setminus B= A\setminus B= A$.  So if $x\in B$ the $x$ is removed for $A$ to get $A\setminus B$ so $x\not \in A$.

Etc.