# Prove that for all sets A and B, A ∩ B = ∅ implies ( A ∪ B ) - B = A

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification, alternative-proof

In the next proof we avail ourselves of the next lemma:

For all sets A and B, ( A ∪ B ) - B = A.

Proof:

Let A and B be arbitrary sets and let x ∈ ( A ∪ B ) - B.

x ∈ ( A ∪ B ) - B ⇔ x ∈ ( A ∪ B ) ∧ x ∉ B ⇔ ( x ∈ A ∨ x ∈ B ) ∧ x ∉ B ⇔ ( x ∈ A ∧ x ∉ B ) ∨ ( x ∈ B ∨ x ∉ B)

For p ∧ ~ p ≡ F and p ∧ q ⇒ p where p and q are prepositions,

( x ∈ A ∧ x ∉ B ) ∨ ( x ∈ B ∨ x ∉ B ) ⇔ x ∈ A ∨ F

By modus tollendo ponens,

x ∈ A ∨ F ⇔ x ∈ A

So then,

x ∈ ( A ∪ B ) - B ⇔ x ∈ A

And

( A ∪ B ) - B = A

Therefore, the statement for all sets A and B, A ∩ B = ∅  implies ( A ∪ B ) - B = A is true trivially.

Is this proof right?

Comment: No.  $(A\cup B)\setminus B \ne A$.  Take $A=\{1,2\}$ and $B = \{2,3\}$ then $(A\cup B)\setminus B= \{1\} \ne A$.

Comment: What if $A=B\ne \emptyset$?

Comment: "( x ∈ A ∧ x ∉ B ) ∨ ( x ∈ B ∨ x ∉ B ) ⇔ x ∈ A ∨ F" uh....no.....  $x\in B\land x\not \in B$ is $F$ so so $(x\in A \land x\not \in B)$ is true.  BUt $(x\in A \land x\not \in B)$ is *NOT* equivalent to $x\in A$.  You have $( x ∈ A ∧ x ∉ B ) ∨ ( x ∈ B ∨ x ∉ B ) ⇔(A\in A\land x \not \in B)\lor F\iff (x\in A\land x \not \in B) \implies x\in A$ but $(x\in A\land x\not \in B)\not \Leftarrow x\in A$.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset mathematics. It ensures proper typesetting. Yours gets badly broked across lines in my display. I fixed your previous one, which was tedious and is what allowed you to use the exact same title for this post (something else we don’t allow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $$B \subset A, B \ne \emptyset, A \setminus B = C \ne \emptyset$$
Then, because B is non empty
$$A \cup B = A \ne A \setminus B$$

Answer (score 0):

$A\cap B=\varnothing\implies A\subset \bar B\implies A\cap \bar B=A$

Thus $(A\cup B)-B=(A\cup B)\cap\bar B=(A\cap\bar B)\cup(B\cap\bar B)=A\cup\varnothing=A$